# Include vector graphics/icons as just a class in a span in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

As clearly given on [this bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons), to include a glypicon icon inside our web page, all we have to do is mention it's class inside a span element, as done here:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

How, we have a few files in .ai format which can be converted to any format of choice (.jpg, .png, .svg, etc...).

I want to know as to how this is implemented, in what format are the files, what's the JS and/or CSS code to be included apart from the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of the Bootstrap page, they have done this by making the icons a font. I would suggest using this method as it is a easy and compact way to do it. You can use a font editor like this: http://icomoon.io/app/#/select

It seems to have pretty decent support for uploading SVG's to it so you can make your own font.

you can then import your font in css like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my-vector-font';
    src: url('my-vector-font.eot');
    src: local('my-vector-font'), 
         local('my-vector-font'), 
         url('my-vector-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('my-vector-font.svg#font') format('svg'); 
}
```

...and then use it in css like:

```
.icon-1:before {
    font-family: 'my-vector-font';
    content: "{CHARACTER_FOR_ICON}";
}
```

You can tune up that selector with padding, etc.. as you need.

Comment: Will it be possible to use this technique even for big and complex svg files?

Comment: @coder, with SVG, 'big' is not an issue. Complex however is. But the best way is to try it out as this is about the only fully cross-browser way to do it. When you export your Illustrator files there should be an option to export the points to 'x'- many decimal places. Exporting to 1 decimal place is fine and lowers the complexity of the SVG a bucket load.

Comment: Does this iconmoon.io helps you convert svg into font?

Comment: @coder if you just click the import button, it looks like you just select the svg icon and then it puts it in the font.